# Fusion Table API : query don't get <innerBoundaryIs> elements in Location column

Tags: java, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to get the contents of a Fusion Table Location column
This column contains a Polygon with "outerBoundaryIs" and "innerBoundaryIs"

I'm querying the column with [Fusion Tables API Query:sql](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/query/sql), but the response don't get the "innerBoundaryIs" elements

I'm using the Fusion Tables Java Library v1r33lv1.15.0-rc

Any direction is appreciated

Lluís

Comment: What is your table (if it is public)?

Comment: Yes, type: "select geometry from 18AfDIZumYMzI8FMluJ1iKFNy4h8WfJ_W5cz6wh8 where ID_CP=330600000060" and you could check that is returned outerBoundary only. This location has also two innerBoundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `typed`-parameter to `false` (default is `true`)

**`<edit>`**:

I don't know why(I haven't found anything about this in any documentation), but for me it works when I add a linebreak **after** the closing **`</outerBoundaryIs>`**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LsCLV/  (it's a copy of your table, the only difference is the linebreak)

Comment: I've checked before. It gives the same results typed and untyped

Comment: Nice, that's true !!! Any idea how to implement a massive detection ? This fusion table comes from a shapefile converted with http://www.shpescape.com/

Comment: Finally I've checked manually the 52 tables with the find tool in  default Google Fusion Tables GUI. I found other 18 polygons with innerBoundaries inside, but surprisingly all were OK. Thanks a million @Dr.Molle

Answer (score 0):

The query from the Fusion Tables API will not return KML. Look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/query/sql) for what the 2 types (JSON, CSV) will look like, neither includes the InnerBoundaryIs (or outerBoundaryIs) elements.

If you *need* the KML, it will be returned if you use the [google visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) query, but that is limited to returning 500 rows.

[Query using Fusion Tables API v1.0 and parse response to native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=43.308686&lng=-5.608074&zoom=13&type=m&tableid=18AfDIZumYMzI8FMluJ1iKFNy4h8WfJ_W5cz6wh8&tablequery=geometry&tablewhere=ID_CP%3D330600000060)

Comment: That's the reason why I cannot use Google Visualization query. You could check that outerBoundary is returned typing: select geometry from 18AfDIZumYMzI8FMluJ1iKFNy4h8WfJ_W5cz6wh8 where ID_CP=330600000060 But this location has also two innerBoundaries that are omitted in the response

Comment: I have filed a bug with the Fusion Tables API team to look into this. We should not be losing information in the returned KML under any circumstances.